# CefSharp in WinForm C# How to reduce the Application Size

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, cefsharp

I'm using chromium browser CefSharp in my C# Windows form Application the application size was around 10 MB but after CefSharp it's 141 MB
the targeted clients don't have fast internet and it's a new application so I need to publish new version every two days,
if there is a way to reduce that would be perfect, if not is there a way to split the big CefSharp files then the clients can install it only once instead of every time I published new version then they have to install the 141 MB again and again?

Comment: From a CefSharp point of view there isn't much you can do without, you can delete locales that you aren't using. How you distribute it is totally up to you. A new version every two days is highly irregular, you can look at just releasing updates as a binary diff, you can do your own research on that topic.

Comment: thank you for the replay, do you have any links that I can read for binary diff

Comment: Squirrel installer has support I believe https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/master/docs/using/delta-packages.md